# Not showing any csv files in a folder

Tags: python, glob

I'm trying to open all csv files within a given folder and then "perform a calculation". I'm currently trying to use glob but it doesn't see any files in the folder. All the code after this seems to work with a single file path but I imagine im using glob wrong.

```py
path = "C:/build/Files*.csv"

for fileName in glob.glob(path):

    with open(fileName, 'r') as file, \
         open('C:PycharmProjects/Result.csv', 'r') as result_file:

         #perform caluclation
```

Comment: Is the `build` folder really in the root of the C drive?

Comment: If you go to a command prompt, what does `dir C:/build/Files*.csv` show?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you're using `glob()`. If you gave the correct wildcard, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your file path looks like, but perhaps are you missing a `/`?

`path = "C:/build/Files/*.csv"` seems like a file structure that would be more likely.

Answer (score 1):

Either make the path a raw string:

```
path = r"C:/build/Files*.csv"
```

or use double backslash:

```
path = "C:\\build\\Files*.csv"
```

Comment: MS Windows uses backslash for directory separation. String can't preserve it so we backslash it. His example is *nix default format (without c:).

Comment: But `glob.glob('C:/build/files/*.csv')` works fine, even in Windows. And I think you have your examples mixed up. In the first example (using forward slashes) there is no difference in using raw strings or normal strings. The only reason why you would want to use raw strings, is if you would write `r'C:\build\files\*.csv'`. (NB: Personally I don't like raw strings, since they do not escape the last character properly, so it won't work for a directory like `r'C:\Temp\'`.)